# Pandas Append Behavior

Tags: python, pandas

This is something that I'm not quite sure on from the docs.

Say I have two dataframes, with overlapping data.

DF1 has a DateTimeIndex starting at 07:00:00 and ending at 09:30:00.

DF2 has a DateTimeIndex starting at 07:00:00 and ending at 11:30:00.

DF2 is an updated DF1, but some rows may be added as compared to DF1 before the end time of DF1. So DF2 might have 200 rows added from 9:20:00-9:30:00 on the update, and then everything after 09:30:00 also is new of course.

If I use:

```
DF1.append(DF2)
```

Will I get all the rows from DF2 that are new? Or does pandas only go in and take the rows from after the end of DF1? Beyond that, DF2 additions could actually be at the same Time as a DF1 row but it would have different contents. Would pandas handle this as well?

If pandas doesn't handle this, what is the best way to do this myself?

```
In [489]: df
Out[489]:
                     Row1  Row3
2013-11-05 08:00:00     2   NaN
2013-11-05 09:00:00     4   NaN
2013-11-05 09:06:00     6     5

In [490]: df2
Out[490]:
                     Row1  Row3
2013-11-05 08:00:00     2   NaN
2013-11-05 09:00:00     5   NaN
2013-11-05 09:09:00     6     5

In [491]: df.append(df2)
Out[491]:
                     Row1  Row3
2013-11-05 08:00:00     2   NaN
2013-11-05 09:00:00     4   NaN
2013-11-05 09:06:00     6     5
2013-11-05 08:00:00     2   NaN
2013-11-05 09:00:00     5   NaN
2013-11-05 09:09:00     6     5
```

I want df.append(df2) in this case to be:

```
In [491]: df.append(df2)
Out[491]:
                     Row1  Row3
2013-11-05 08:00:00     2   NaN
2013-11-05 09:00:00     4   NaN
2013-11-05 09:06:00     6     5
<strike>2013-11-05 08:00:00     2   NaN</strike>
2013-11-05 09:00:00     5   NaN
2013-11-05 09:09:00     6     5
```

edit2:

I was previously doing this:

```
last = df.ix[-1].name
to_append = df2[last:]
new_df = df.append(to_append)
```

This unfortunately cuts out the rows that are new but before the timestamp of the last row of my previous DataFrame

Answer (score 4):

Append is similar to one of python `list`, you will get both dataframes "stacked" together. Whether a `ValueError` is raised in case of indexes with duplicates is controlled by `verify_integrity` param to `append`, defaulting to `False`.

```
>>> df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict({'col':{'row': 1}})
>>> df
     col
row    1
>>> df.append(df).index
Index([u'row', u'row'], dtype=object)
>>> df.append(df)
     col
row    1
row    1

>>> df.append(df, verify_integrity=True)
Traceback (most recent call last):
   ...
ValueError: Indexes have overlapping values: ['row']
```

for merging with replacement use `combine_first`:

```
>>> mdf = pd.DataFrame.from_dict({'col':{'row': 2, 'new':3}})
>>> df.combine_first(mdf) # values from df overwrite those of mdf
     col
new    3
row    1
>>> mdf.combine_first(df) # values from mdf overwrite those of df
     col
new    3
row    2
```

For the reference, here is [extensive guide](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/dev/merging.html) on different merge and join means of dataframes

**UPDATE**

Followup: as you wish behaviour similar to `SQL union`, one approach migth be:

```
>>> df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict({'col':{'row': 1, 'new': 3}})
>>> mdf.append(df).drop_duplicates()
     col
new    3
row    2
row    1
```

Or if you want to take index in account,

```
>>> mdf['index'] = mdf.index
>>> df['index'] = df.index
>>> union = mdf.append(df).drop_duplicates()
>>> del union['index']
>>> union
     col
new    3
row    2
row    1
```

Comment: I guess I'm asking a bit more in depth than this. What I really need is a veryify_integrity=True except it skips those that are duplicates but it also checks every column to make sure it is a duplicate not only in index but also content and if it isn't then it will join the df as well

Comment: @user1610719 You should add a by-hand example of what you expect, your comment is unclear

Comment: Not sure how to strike but I added it

Comment: Not sure how else to describe it but what I want is: Merge two dataframes even if they have the same index, but if they do have the same index I want to not merge when all the resulting columns also match. So merge all but those rows that are exact duplicates

Comment: I edited out the last one. I'd lose something like 20k rows by merging using combine_first. So the way two comments above is the only way it would work for me. Append wouldn't work as it keeps all the and I'm dealing with like 10m rows that are the same and 2k updated rows and 200 rows earlier than the end of the first df also being different. I also edited with my old way of doing it

Comment: Doing this drops any duplicates from axis=1, right? I tried this with my example from above and while the 2nd 08:00:00 was gone(correct), the 09:09:00 was also gone because it's columns matched 09:06:00 even though the index did not

Comment: Yep just thought of this. I'm hoping there is a faster more pandas way of doing this, but this is what I'm going to use currently